# PhoneGap root path

Tags: android, cordova, mobile

I'm making an app for Android using PhoneGap.  The app basically redirects to a website for mobile.  I have videos that I want to include with the app, so that the users can view them without internet.  From a page online, how can I link to the root directory of the app, not the website?

So basically, the app redirects to `mobile.website.com`.  The user clicks on "Video", and it goes to the app root directory.  How do I link to this; what is the path for the app?

Thanks!

EDIT: I'm using PhoneGap Build.

Comment: Sorry it's not clear if you want to play videos from your phone in your pohnegap app or if you want to download a video from your mobile.website.com and store it in your phone.

Comment: @gameower Sorry-I want to play a video from the app, and I want the video to be on the local app files in PhoneGap, not on the web.  That way it can be viewed offline.